# Python Selenium: How to navigate Javascript based navigation

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

So the page in question is [here](http://www.leparking.fr/voiture-occasion/Porsche--targa-g.html#!/voiture-occasion/Porsche--targa-g.html%3Fslider_millesime%3D1940%7C1985), I want to navigate pagination having following markup:

```
 <li class="btn-next">
<a href="javascript:ctrl.set_pageReload(2)">Suivant</a></li>
```

If you notice, JS method is being called here. So far I have done this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = None
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)


def fetch(url):
    driver.get(
        'http://www.leparking.fr/voiture-occasion/Porsche--targa-g.html#!/voiture-occasion/Porsche--targa-g.html%3Fslider_millesime%3D1940%7C1985')

    elem_more = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Suivant")))
    elem_more.click()


fetch(None)
```

It does hover the element but does not navigate on click. What should I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I sorted it out by using `execute_script` method:

```
elem_more = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Suivant")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", elem_more)
```